# Does django create a clean database?

Tags: django, database-design, maintainability

I am building a web interface for a database at my school.  The database will hold our school's versions of academic standards.

When you build a site using django, does it create a clean database?  For example, wysiwyg website builders like dreamweaver create ugly html and css code on the backend.  I would hate to see a similar degree of auto-generated cruft in my database.

Should I create the database myself and then build a django site to access the database, or go ahead and let django create the database?

Comment: Is your question: does django put html and css into the database?  If that is your question, the answer is: no, django does not put HTML and CSS into the database.

Comment: I see the confusion.  I know it does not put hmtl and css into the database.  I meant to ask if there was a similar degree of cruft in the auto-generated database.
I will go ahead and give django a try.

Comment: If you give Django a try, make sure you use South, virtualenv and pip. I cannot stress how helpful these three tools are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under any simple to moderately complex application, Django will do a fine job creating the database for you. I've yet to run into any issues with what it's made.

I would suggest that you use [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) to handle your table migrations. And use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/) to set up and maintain your Django environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sqlall` predicate of `manage.py` to see the exact SQL that will be executed in order to generate the database.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously django [needs database tables](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/#database-setup) for its basic functionality (contrib.apps).

Sure, you don't have to use them, but generally you want to use a least contrib.auth and some other bundled apps:

> Each of these applications makes use
>   of at least one database table,
>   though, so we need to create the
>   tables in the database before we can
>   use them.

I any case you can't and shouldn't compare it to ugly html code generated by dreamweaver or word.

---

On a more abstract level:

One of key concepts of a web framework (following the mvc pattern) is that you define models which are "translated" (mapped) by the framework into database tables.

> A model is the single, definitive
>   source of data about your data. It
>   contains the essential fields and
>   behaviors of the data you’re storing.
>   Generally, each model maps to a single
>   database table.

If you want to create the whole database scheme by hand you totally missed the point of using a web framework. In most cases you simply don't need to write `sql` manually. You define your classes and then you can query your objects using the builtin [orm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#making-queries).

Comment: I know it needs database tables.  I was wondering if it generates good clean database structure.  Thank you for your response.